# MVC Sending collection and referenced object to a view from BeginForm?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

My question is: How to pass Collections and Referenced object types without writing so many HiddenFors?

This is my model:

```
public partial class AddressObject
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string KeyNumber { get; set; }
    public int AddressID { get; set; }
    public int ObjectTypeID { get; set; }
    public double ResidentalArea { get; set; }
    public short ResidentsNumber { get; set; }
    public Nullable<short> TuristBedsNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
    public virtual ObjectType ObjectType { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TrashCan> TrashCans { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ObjectOwner> ObjectOwners { get; set; }
}
```

This is my View:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Address.CityID);
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Address.Hood);
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Address.ID);
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Address.Number);
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Address.Region);
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Address.Street);
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Address.City.Addresses);
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Address.City.ID);
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Address.City.Name);
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Address.City.PostalCode);   
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AddressID);
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ObjectOwners);
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ObjectType.ID);
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ObjectType.Type);
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ObjectTypeID);
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TrashCans);
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TuristBedsNumber);
```

I don't want to write everything for Address. I just want to pass Address. My collection is ObjectOwners. I want to do the same thing. Solution exists?

EDIT: I have `Controller` and method in in it `ActionResult(AddressObject addressObject)`. Inside that controller, I'm calling a `unitOfWork` with repository for saving that entity. My 
HiddenFors are wrapped with `@HtmlBeginForm("Save", "AddressObject")`. When I pass my model to controller, my Address object `AddressObject.Address` is `null = Count 0`. I want to be able to pass whole object with my referenced objects and collection without writing hiddenfors for all properties of referenced object or collection.

**EDIT2:**
I have master detail scenario(that's not matter), textboxes are binded to AddressObject for my View's model. So I have @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AddressID) for example. The problem is, when I change for example AddressObject.TurisBedsNumber, every referenced object or collection become null and because of that my AddressObject is not persistent when it is passed from View to the Controller back with my updated properties. I want my references and other properties be untouched as they were before Updating. I've tried with Mvc Futures and Serializing whole object and my object and its collections and referenced objects are ok. The problem is, when I deserialize my object, that object is not updated with new TuristBedNumber properties; it's old value. I want to know how to save state of my collection and other objects. I can save my state with HiddenFor helper (too many properties to write) or I could get AddressObject or Collection from my repository and update it in my controller; again, too many properties. I want to be able to say "hey you collection and my referenced objects, you'll not change no matter what". I want to serialize them whole, but only them. 
Someone asked for controller but it is common:

```
public ActionResult(AddressObject addressObject) { unitOfWork.Update(addressObject) }
```

Yes I have ValidState etc....

Comment: Could you give more context? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: In your controller Before passing the model, you should request it properly by a Linq query to retrieve also `Adress`. If you update your question with the controller, it could be easier to help you

Comment: Why do you want to pass so many things to the view that you don't want to display?  This is typically not a good thing to do.  You would be better off saving this data somewhere rather than passing it around.  By the way, you can't pass an IColection to HiddenFor like that...

Comment: Again edited: comment too long, see EDIT2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a helper class I use for creating hidden inputs for properties.  If the property is a complex type, its called recursively to create hidden inputs for each property of the complex type. In your case you would use @Html.HiddenInputFor(m => m.Address) to generate all 17 inputs.  Be sure to add the namespace in your web.config.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Sandtrap.Web.Extensions;

namespace Sandtrap.Web.Html
{

/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
public static class HiddenInputHelper
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the html for a hidden input(s) of a property.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TModel"></typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TValue"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="helper"></param>
    /// <param name="expression"></param>
    /// <param name="includeID">
    /// A value indicating the the 'id' attribute should be rendered for the input.
    /// </param>
    /// <remarks>
    /// If the property is a complex type, the methods is called recursively for each property
    /// of the type. Collections and complex types with null value (except those with the 
    /// Required attribute) are ignored.
    /// </remarks>
    public static MvcHtmlString HiddenInputFor<TModel, TValue>
        (this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, bool includeID = false)
    {
        string name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
        ModelMetadata metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData);
        StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(HiddenInput(metaData, name, includeID));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the html for a hidden input(s) of a property defined by its metadata.
    /// The string is not html-encoded.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="metaData">
    /// The metadata of the property.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="name">
    /// The name of the property (rendered as the 'name' attribute).
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="includeID">
    /// A value indicating the the 'id' attribute should be rendered for the input.
    /// </param>
    /// <remarks>
    /// If the property is a complex type, the methods is called recursively for each property
    /// of the type. Collections and complex types with null value (except those with the 
    /// Required attribute) are ignored.
    /// </remarks>
    public static string HiddenInputForMetadata(ModelMetadata metaData, string name, bool includeID = false)
    {
        return HiddenInput(metaData, name, includeID);
    }

    #region .Helper methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the html for a hidden input(s) of a property.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="metaData">
    /// The property metadata.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="name">
    /// The name of the property (rendered as the 'name' attribute).
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="includeID">
    /// A value indicating the the 'id' attribute should be rendered for the input.
    /// </param>
    private static string HiddenInput(ModelMetadata metaData, string name, bool includeID)
    {
        StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
        if (metaData.ModelType.IsArray && metaData.Model != null)
        {
            // Primarily for database time stamps, this need to called before checking IsComplexType
            // otherwise an endless loop is created
            html.Append(HiddenInput(name, Convert.ToBase64String(metaData.Model as byte[]), includeID));
        }
        else if (metaData.IsComplexType)
        {
            foreach (ModelMetadata property in metaData.Properties)
            {
                if (property.IsCollection() && !property.ModelType.IsArray)
                {
                    // This would just render the Count and Capacity property of List<T>
                    continue;
                }
                if (property.Model == null && property.ModelType != typeof(string) && !property.IsRequired)
                {
                    // Ignore complex types that are null and do not have the RequiredAttribute
                    continue;
                }
                // Recursive call to render a hidden input for the property
                string prefix = string.Format("{0}.{1}", name, property.PropertyName);
                html.Append(HiddenInput(property, prefix, includeID));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            html.Append(HiddenInput(name, metaData.Model, includeID));
        }
        return html.ToString();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the html for a hidden input.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name">
    /// The name of the property.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="value">
    /// The value of the property.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="includeID">
    /// A value indicating the the 'id' attribute should be rendered for the input.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static string HiddenInput(string name, object value, bool includeID)
    {
        TagBuilder input = new TagBuilder("input");
        input.MergeAttribute("type", "hidden");
        if (includeID)
        {
            input.MergeAttribute("id", HtmlHelper.GenerateIdFromName(name));
        }
        input.MergeAttribute("name", name);
        input.MergeAttribute("value", string.Format("{0}", value));
        return input.ToString();
    }

    #endregion

}

}
```

The following extension method is also required

```
    public static bool IsCollection(this ModelMetadata metaData)
    {
        if (metaData.ModelType == typeof(string))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(metaData.ModelType);
    }
```